# How to send multipart/form-data with Retrofit?

Tags: android, image-uploading, multipartform-data, retrofit

I want to send an *Article* from and *Android* client to a REST server. Here is the *Python* model from the server:

```
class Article(models.Model):
    author = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank=False)
    photo = models.ImageField()
```

The following interface describes the former implementation:

```
@POST("/api/v1/articles/")
public Observable<CreateArticleResponse> createArticle(
        @Body Article article
);
```

Now I want to send an image with the *Article* data. The `photo` is not part of the *Article* model on the *Android* client.

```
@Multipart
@POST("/api/v1/articles/")
public Observable<CreateArticleResponse> createArticle(
        @Part("article") Article article,
        @Part("photo") TypedFile photo
);
```

The API is prepared and successfully tested with *cURL*.

```
$ curl -vX POST http://localhost:8000/api/v1/articles/ \
    -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" \
    -H "Accept:application/json" \
    -F "author=cURL" \
    -F "photo=@/home/user/Desktop/article-photo.png"
```

When I send data through `createArticle()` from the *Android* client I receive an `HTTP 400` status stating that the **fields are required/missing**.

```
D  <--- HTTP 400 http://192.168.1.1/articles/ (2670ms)
D  Date: Mon, 20 Apr 2015 12:00:00 GMT
D  Server: WSGIServer/0.1 Python/2.7.8
D  Vary: Accept, Cookie
D  X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
D  Content-Type: application/json
D  Allow: GET, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS
D  OkHttp-Selected-Protocol: http/1.0
D  OkHttp-Sent-Millis: 1429545450469
D  OkHttp-Received-Millis: 1429545453120
D  {"author":["This field is required."],"photo":["No file was submitted."]}
D  <--- END HTTP (166-byte body)
E  400 BAD REQUEST
```

This is what is received as `request.data` on the server side:

```
ipdb> print request.data  
  <QueryDict: {u'article': [u'{"author":"me"}'], \
  u'photo': [<TemporaryUploadedFile: IMG_1759215522.jpg \
  (multipart/form-data)>]}>
```

How can convert the *Article* object in a multipart conform data type? I read that [*Retrofit*](http://square.github.io/retrofit/) might allow to use [Converters](https://github.com/square/retrofit/tree/master/retrofit-converters) for this. It should be something that implements a `retrofit.mime.TypedOutput` as far as I understood for the [documentation](http://square.github.io/retrofit/).

> Multipart parts use the `RestAdapter`'s converter or they can implement `TypedOutput` to handle their own serialization.

## Related

- [HTML 4.01 Specification - Form submission - multipart/form-data](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.2)
- [Retrofit Annotation Type Part documentation](http://square.github.io/retrofit/javadoc/retrofit/http/Part.html)
- [Upload multipart image data in JSON with Retrofit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24165605/upload-multipart-image-data-in-json-with-retrofit-android)
- [REST - HTTP Post Multipart with JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9081079/rest-http-post-multipart-with-json)
- [Retrofit Multipart Upload Image failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28348269/retrofit-multipart-upload-image-failed)
- [Retrofit issue #178: Create manual for sending files with retrofit](https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/178)
- [Retrofit issue #531: Problem uploading file via POST/Multipart](https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/531)
- [Retrofit issue #658: Not able to send string parameters with image when using Multipart](https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/658)
- [Retrofit issue #662: Retrofit Form Encoded and Multipart in single request](https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/662)

Comment: Isn't it the TypedFile class that can be used for this?

Comment: Your method appears to be fine. Why don't you enable logging on the `RestAdapter` and check exactly what data is being sent.

Comment: @user2511882 Do you mean I should use `TypedFile` for both the JSON data (`article`) and the image? Please point me to how to convert the data. / @corsair992 I updated my post.

Comment: Are you sure that you need multipart request? I have seen some servers that expects JSON object as POST body with image binary data posted as string. Like this: `{"author":"authorNameHere","photo":"base64ImageBytesHere"]}`. If this is the case I can provide the code on how to do that with Okio and Retrofit.

Comment: I just saw that you have working curl request, could you post it, please?

Comment: @SergiiPechenizkyi I added the *cURL* command. I read about the `base64` option but it feels like it should be `multipart/form-data` ... please convince me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

According to your curl request you are trying to create smth like this:

```
POST http://localhost:8000/api/v1/articles/ HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: curl/7.30.0
Host: localhost
Connection: Keep-Alive
Accept: application/json
Content-Length: 183431
Expect: 100-continue
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----------------------------23473c7acabb

------------------------------23473c7acabb
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="author"

cURL
------------------------------23473c7acabb
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="photo"; filename="article-photo.png"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream

‰PNG

<!RAW BYTES HERE!>

M\UUÕ+4qUUU¯°WUUU¿×ß¿þ Naa…k¿    IEND®B`‚
------------------------------23473c7acabb--
```

With retrofit adapter this request can be created in a next way:

```
@Multipart
@POST("/api/v1/articles/")
Observable<Response> uploadFile(@Part("author") TypedString authorString,
                                @Part("photo") TypedFile photoFile);
```

Usage:

```
TypedString author = new TypedString("cURL");
File photoFile = new File("/home/user/Desktop/article-photo.png");
TypedFile photoTypedFile = new TypedFile("image/*", photoFile);
retrofitAdapter.uploadFile(author, photoTypedFile)
               .subscribe(<...>);
```

Which creates similar output:

```
POST http://localhost:8000/api/v1/articles/ HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=32230279-83af-4480-abfc-88a880b21b19
Content-Length: 709
Host: localhost
Connection: Keep-Alive
Accept-Encoding: gzip
User-Agent: okhttp/2.3.0

--32230279-83af-4480-abfc-88a880b21b19
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="author"
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 4
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

cUrl
--32230279-83af-4480-abfc-88a880b21b19
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="photo"; filename="article-photo.png"
Content-Type: image/*
Content-Length: 254
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

<!RAW BYTES HERE!>

--32230279-83af-4480-abfc-88a880b21b19--
```

The key difference here is that you used POJO `Article article` as multipart param, which by default is converted by `Converter` into json. And your server expects plain string instead. With curl you are sending `cURL`, not `{"author":"cURL"}`.

Comment: Is it possible to convert the whole *Article* model into a `Typed..` at once and pass it to the API instead of pulling out each member? Maybe a converter could do this?

Comment: Yes, absolutely. I haven't seen such converter, you may want to write it and tailor to your needs. Sample direction: https://gist.github.com/plastiv/08538a095d2d35acab05.

Comment: For reference: I proposed the [MultipartConverter as a feature for Retrofit](https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/819).

Comment: What imports are needed for `TypedString` and `TypedFile`? Autocomplete isn't giving me any suggestions. Are these from an older version of Retrofit? If so, what are they repalced with? Or are they from another library I need to add to my dependencies?

Answer (score 2):

The server expects an "author" string but you're trying to pass it an "article" object. Pass it "String author" instead of "Article article."

Also, I think the "no file submitted" error is a red herring because the file is clearly present in your "request.data."