# How to post data using multipart?

Tags: android, android-camera, multipartform-data

I develop one app. In my app i take one image from camera or one from gallery. I want to post image to server using Multipart but image not post it. My post data is below

```
{
     "suggested_item" :{
         "name": "apple",
         "description" : "nice apple", 
         "image": "image.png"
     }
  }
```

My java code is

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

if (requestCode == PICK_FROM_CAMERA) {
    try{
        if(resultCode == -1){
            File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+File.separator +"image.png");
            bitmap = loadBitmap(file);
            iv_pic.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

        try {
            Uri tempUri = getImageUri(getActivity(), bitmap);
            Log.i(TAG,"onActivityResult PICK_FROM_CAMERA, tempUri : "+tempUri);

        //uploadFile(tempUri + "" + System.currentTimeMillis()+".png");
        } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
        }else{
        //setResult(RESULT_CANCELED);
        //Activity.this.finish();
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}else if (requestCode == PICK_FROM_GALLERY) {
        try{
           //Log.i(TAG,"onActivityResult PICK_FROM_GALLERY, data : "+data);
            if(data !=null){
                bitmap = null;
                try {
                    bitmap = new BitmapDrawable(MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getActivity().getContentResolver(), data.getData())).getBitmap();
                    iv_pic.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

                    try {
                        Uri tempUri = getImageUri(getActivity(), bitmap);
                        Log.i(TAG,"onActivityResult PICK_FROM_GALLERY, tempUri : "+tempUri);

                        //uploadFile(tempUri + "" + System.currentTimeMillis()+".png");
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }else{
                //setResult(RESULT_CANCELED);
                //Activity.this.finish();
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

public Uri getImageUri(Context context , Bitmap bitmap) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG , 100 , bytes);
    String path = Images.Media.insertImage(context.getContentResolver() , bitmap , "Title" , null);
    return Uri.parse(path);
}
```

please help me thanks in advance.

Comment: you want to upload image to server ?

Comment: yes, above is my postdata .....i post name and description but problem with  image. this  is my code ...JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject();
     JSONObject child_obj = new JSONObject();
     child_obj.put("name", name);
     child_obj.put("description", description);
     
     
     //child_obj.put("image", image);
     jsonObj.put("suggested_item", child_obj);......now  i want send image with multipart form data..

Answer (score 0):

To send binary data you need to use addBinaryBody method of MultipartEntityBuilder. Sample of attaching:

```
import org.apache.http.entity.ContentType;
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartEntityBuilder;
//Image attaching
MultipartEntityBuilder multipartEntity = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
File file;
multipartEntity.addBinaryBody("someName", file, ContentType.create("image/jpeg"), file.getName());
//Json string attaching
String json;
multipartEntity.addPart("someName", new StringBody(json, ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN));
```

Then make request as usual:

```
HttpPut put = new HttpPut("url");
put.setEntity(multipartEntity.build());
HttpResponse response = client.execute(put);
int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using [retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/).

Posting multipart will be something like this:

```
@Multipart
@PUT("user/photo")
Call<User> updateUser(@Part("photo") RequestBody photo, @Part("description") RequestBody description);
```

Refer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29680158/how-to-send-multipart-form-data-with-retrofit) for more details.

[This](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Consuming-APIs-with-Retrofit) is a good tutorial to check if you are not familiar to retrofit.

Answer (score 0):

Here I am Posting Full Code for Upload Image Using HTTP on Server also PHP code for understanding,

Class File

```
package com.stackexmples;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

/**
 * Created by windws on 26-Mar-16.
 */
public class UploadImage extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    private static final int REQUEST_TAKE_GALLERY_VIDEO = 11;
    private static final String TAG = "UploadMultipleFile";
    private AppCompatButton btnUploadFiles;
    private AppCompatButton bntSelectImage;
    private String filemanagerstring;
    private String selectedImagePath="";
    private TextView tvVideoList;
    private TextView tvImageList;
    private int selected = 0;
    private LinearLayout ll;
    private int count = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_upload_multiple_file);
        initView();
        initListener();

    }

    private void initView() {
        btnUploadFiles = (AppCompatButton) findViewById(R.id.btnUploadFiles);
        bntSelectImage = (AppCompatButton) findViewById(R.id.bntSelectImage);
    }

    private void initListener() {
        btnUploadFiles.setOnClickListener(this);
        bntSelectImage.setOnClickListener(this);
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v == btnUploadFiles) {
            Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    uploadFile("Data you want to sent");
                }
            });
            thread.start();
        } else if (v == bntSelectImage) {
            selectImage();
        }
    }

    private void selectImage() {
        selected = 1;
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("Image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Image"), REQUEST_TAKE_GALLERY_VIDEO);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            if (requestCode == REQUEST_TAKE_GALLERY_VIDEO) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Called-->onActivityResultCalled");
                Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
                Log.d(TAG, "selectedImageUri-->" + selectedImageUri);
                selectedImagePath = selectedImageUri.toString().replace("file://", "");
            }
        }
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    public String uploadFile(String req) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String serverResponseMessage = "";
        String response_return = "";
        Log.d("first str is:", req);
        String urlString = "http://192.168.1.32/TestUpload/upload.php";
        URL imageUrl = null;
        try {
            imageUrl = new URL(urlString); // get WebService_URL
        } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        String lineEnd = "\r\n";
        String twoHyphens = "--";
        String boundary = "*****";
        // generating byte[] boundary here

        HttpURLConnection conn = null;
        DataOutputStream outputStream = null;

        int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
        byte[] buffer;
        int maxBufferSize = 10 * 1024 * 1024;

        try {
            int serverResponseCode;
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) imageUrl.openConnection();
            conn.setConnectTimeout(10000);
            conn.setReadTimeout(10000);
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
            outputStream = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

            //////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
            outputStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"json\"" + lineEnd);
            outputStream.writeBytes("Content-Type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8" + lineEnd);
            outputStream.writeBytes("Content-Length: " + req.length() + lineEnd);
            outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
            outputStream.writeBytes(req + lineEnd);
            outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
            try {
                FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(selectedImagePath);
                String lastOne = "temp";
                /////////////////////////////////////////////
                outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
                outputStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: attachment;  name=\"imageKey" + "\";" + " filename=" + lastOne +".jpg" + lineEnd); // pass key & value of photo
                    /*outputStream.writeBytes("Content-Type: application/octet-stream" + lineEnd);*/
                outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available(); // photo size bytes
                bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
                // Read file
                bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                while (bytesRead > 0) {
                    outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                    bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                    bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                    bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                }
                outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                Log.d("posttemplate", "connection outputstream size is " + outputStream.size());
                fileInputStream.close();
            } catch (OutOfMemoryError o) {
            }
            outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);
            serverResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
            serverResponseMessage = conn.getResponseMessage();
            InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
            String line;
            StringBuffer response1 = new StringBuffer();
            while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                response1.append(line);
                response1.append('\r');
            }
            rd.close();
            response_return = response1.toString();

            Log.d("posttemplate", "server response code " + serverResponseCode);
            Log.d("posttemplate", "server response message "
                    + serverResponseMessage);
            outputStream.flush();
            outputStream.close();
            conn.disconnect();

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            Log.d("posttemplate", "malformed url", e);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d("posttemplate", "ioexception", e);
        }
        Log.d("response--->", "****" + response_return);
        return response_return;
    }
}
```

Layout File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.materialexample.UploadMultipleFile.UploadMultipleFile">
    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/btnUploadFiles"
        android:text="Upload Files" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_below="@id/btnUploadFiles"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
            android:id="@+id/bntSelectImage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Select Image" />

    </LinearLayout>



</RelativeLayout>
```

PHP Code For Understanding

```
<?php
$file_path = "uploads/";

    $file_path = $file_path . basename( $_FILES['imageKey']['name']);
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['imageKey']['tmp_name'], $file_path)) {
        echo "success";
    } else{
        echo "fail";
    }
if(isset($_REQUEST['json'])){
    echo "text is-->".$_REQUEST['json'];
}

?>
```