# is it possible to pass a single item as multipart using retrofit?

Tags: android, retrofit, multipart

```
 @Multipart
@POST("/api/add-deal/")
public void addDeal(@Body Deal deal, @Part("image")TypedFile image,Callback<Response> callback);
```

I want to send only the image as multipart and the rest as is.Is there any possible way ? Even I tried to add TypedFile inside my Deal model but unable to annotate with @part

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible with Partmap annotation using hash map. For example-

```
    @Multipart
    @POST("/api/add-deal/")
    Call<Response> addDeal(@PartMap 
    HashMap<String, RequestBody> hashMap);
```

In hashMap you can add no of url parameters as key and set your values using RequestBody class type. see how to convert String and Image to RequestBody.

```
    public static RequestBody ImageToRequestBody(File file) { //for image file to request body
           return RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/*"),file);
    }

    public static RequestBody StringToRequestBody(String string){ // for string to request body
           return RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"),string);
    }
```

add params to hashmap-

```
    hashMap.put("photo",ImageToRequestBody(imageFile)); //your imageFile to Request body.
    hashMap.put("user_id",StringToRequestBody("113"));
    //calling addDeal method
    apiInterface.addDeal(hashMap);
```

Hope this helpful.

Comment: I don't get this ! :/

Comment: What did you tried? Is there any issue in Request Body ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you can send your @Body as TypedString.
For example, convert your "@Body Deal deal" into JSON String, and send it as TypedString.

Details: [How to send multipart/form-data with Retrofit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29680158/how-to-send-multipart-form-data-with-retrofit)

```
@Multipart
@POST("/api/v1/articles/")
Observable<Response> uploadFile(@Part("author") TypedString authorString,
                                @Part("photo") TypedFile photoFile);
```

Comment: Thanks.Let me try this.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me: [POST Multipart Form Data using Retrofit 2.0 including image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34562950/post-multipart-form-data-using-retrofit-2-0-including-image)

```
public interface ApiInterface {

    @Multipart
    @POST("/api/Accounts/editaccount")
    Call<User> editUser (@Header("Authorization") String authorization, @Part("file\"; filename=\"pp.png\" ") RequestBody file , @Part("FirstName") RequestBody fname, @Part("Id") RequestBody id);
    }

    File file = new File(imageUri.getPath());
    RequestBody fbody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/*"), file);
    RequestBody name = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), firstNameField.getText().toString());
    RequestBody id = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), AZUtils.getUserId(this));
    Call<User> call = client.editUser(AZUtils.getToken(this), fbody, name, id);

    call.enqueue(new Callback<User>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(retrofit.Response<User> response, Retrofit retrofit) {
            AZUtils.printObject(response.body());
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
        }
});
```

Comment: can't use Retrofit 2.0.Using 1+