# How to send photo together with another fields with Retrofit?

Tags: android, retrofit2

I have photo and that photo can have comments (optional) and I need to upload both photo and comment if there is some. I am using POST with Multipart for image uploading, but I do not know how to add photo comment to the API.

Here what I have for Retrofit interface:

```
@Multipart
@POST("/v3/work_orders/{work_order_id}/photo_attachments")
Single<Response<ResponseBody>> uploadPhoto(
  @Path("work_order_id") int workOrderId,
  @Part MultipartBody.Part imageBody);
```

Here is how I send data to that Retrofit interface:

```
@Override public Single<Response<ResponseBody>> uploadPhoto(
  int workOrderId, PhotoAttachmentRequest photoAttachmentRequest
) {
RequestBody requestFile =  RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/png"),   photoAttachmentRequest.getAttachment());
MultipartBody.Part imageBody = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData(
    "photo_attachment[attachment]",
    photoAttachmentRequest.getAttachment().getName(),
    requestFile
);
return api.uploadPhoto(workOrderId, imageBody)
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io());
 }
```

How I can send also **photo_attachement[comments]** field?

Comment: I think you can put comments in another MultipartBody. I had some problems with MultipartBody when it comes down to photo, so I asked backend if I can send photo as string (Base64) - it works without problem

This issue should help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29680158/how-to-send-multipart-form-data-with-retrofit?rq=1

Comment: Please check this link, it my help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39953457/how-to-upload-image-file-in-retrofit-2

Comment: If anyone wants to write answer based on those comments, I am glad to accept it.