# Android Retrofit multipart request with two parts

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2, okhttp, multipartfile

I am learning the use of Retrofit2 to make REST Api calls from Android app.  I have an end point which accepts two parts as given below:

```
    @Multipart
    @POST("user/personImageUpload5")
    suspend fun uploadUImage2(

        @Part(value = "person") person: PersonFull,
        @Part personImage: MultipartBody.Part
    ) : BaseResponseModel
```

The end point works well when I test it with postman.

I have generated the postman code snippet in java and converted it to kotlin and the resulting code is listed below:

```
    var client =  OkHttpClient().newBuilder()
        .build();
    var mediaType = "text/plain".toMediaTypeOrNull();
    var body = MultipartBody.Builder().setType(MultipartBody.FORM)
        .addFormDataPart("person", null,
            RequestBody.create(
                "application/json".toMediaTypeOrNull(),
            Gson().toJson(personFull)))
        .addFormDataPart("productImage","/C:/Nazir/eclipseprojects/images/15224.jpeg",
                RequestBody.create(
                    "application/octet-stream".toMediaTypeOrNull(),
                    file))
                .build();
    var request = Request.Builder()
                .url(baseUrl + "user/personImageUpload5")
                .method("POST", body)
                .addHeader("Authorization", token)
                .build();
    return response = client.newCall(request).execute();
```

When I execute, the code works well until the last line where the request is actually executed.  There the execution stays forever and nothing happens. No okhttp messages are logged in logcat either.  Any suggestions and what could be wrong here.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to send multipart/form-data with Retrofit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29680158/how-to-send-multipart-form-data-with-retrofit)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following code worked:

```
    @Multipart
    @POST("user/personImageUpload4")
    suspend fun uploadUImage2(
        @Part("person") person: RequestBody,
        @Part personImage: MultipartBody.Part
    ) : BaseResponseModel
```

Here is how I made the call:

```
val filesDir = context.filesDir
var tempFile = "imagetrf.jpg"
val file = File(filesDir, imageUrlPath)
val inputStream = context.contentResolver.openInputStream(imageUri)
val outputStream = FileOutputStream(file)
   inputStream!!.copyTo(outputStream)
val requestBodyFile = file.asRequestBody("image/*".toMediaTypeOrNull())

val part1 = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("personImage",imageUrlPath, requestBodyFile)

val returnPerson: RequestBody = RequestBody.create("application/json".toMediaTypeOrNull(), Gson().toJson(
                    PersonModel(personFull)
                    ))
var baseResponseModel = savePhotoAPI.uploadUImage2(returnPerson,part1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not calling your uploadUImage2(), Call your this method and pass that multipart data