# How can I send a POJO object in a Multipart-form Request using Retrofit?

Tags: java, android, retrofit, pojo, multipartform-data

I am trying to send the following in a `Multipart-form` request using `Retrofit`:

```
{ "attachment": { 
    "file_cache": "....."
    "original": "upload/image.png",
    "versions": {
        "small": "uploads/small_image.png"
    }
    },
  "content": "",
  "id": 1
}
```

I don't know if this is a correct request I should be sending to the API, since their documentation is really horrible but I was able to use Chrome Dev Tools to study what the API was receiving request wise and how it was responding, it seems to accept that JSON.

Here is a photo of what I observed:

[image]

Their documentation only states that `"attachment"` should be an object.

[image]

Is it possible at all to send a `POJO` object in a `multipart-form` request? My REST Interface looks like this:

```
@Multipart
@POST("/v2/{type}/{id}/message.json")
void addMessage(@Path("type") String type,
                @Path("id") int id,
                @Part("content") String content,
                @Part("attachment") MultipartTypedOutput multipartTypedOutput,
                Callback<Post> callback);
```

Sending a `MultipartTypedOutput` didn't work, neither did using the following:

```
addMessage(...., @Part("attachment") POJOObject object, ...);
```

Any ideas on how to accomplish this?

I get a status `422` un-processable entity if I try to send a `POJO` object with `Retrofit`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to solve this by following this link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24165605/upload-multipart-image-data-in-json-with-retrofit).

I was not aware of this but in order to send `JSON` you need to setup your `REST API Service` like so:

```
@Multipart
@POST("/v2/{type}/{id}/message.json")
void addMessage(@Path("type") String type,
            @Path("id") int id,
            @Part("content") String content,
            @Part("attachment[file_cache]") String fileCache,
            @Part("attachment[original]") String original,
            @Part("attachment[versions][small]") String small,
            Callback<Post> callback);
```

Hopefully this helps someone else out down the road.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried TypedFile ? If not try this way,

```
@Multipart
@POST("/v2/{type}/{id}/message.json")
void addMessage(@Path("type") String type,
                @Path("id") int id,
                @Part("content") String content,
                @Part("attachment") TypedFile photoFile,
                Callback<Post> callback);
```

For TypedFile you can pass attachment this way,

```
File attachmentFile = new File("upload/image.png");
TypedFile attachmentTypedFile = new TypedFile("image/*", photoFile);
```